# How to get maximum number of compositions in complex condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables like follows. in this case two sets(composition) are stored.

`set1`:
`parent:A , child:B×2,C`

`set2`:
`parent:D , child:E,F`

`composition`

```
parent child
A      B
A      B
A      C
D      E
D      F
```

And I have a stock table, which describes how many commodities are stored in some warehouse.

`stock`

```
code  stock
A     3
B     4 
C     3
D     5
E     6
F     7
```

I would like to get number of possible maximum for a set.
`set1` can be made `2`.

stock`B` is 4 ,provided that `set1`needs two B, set number is 4÷2 =`2`

`set2` can be made`6`.

stock `E` is 6,`F` is 7 , considering minimum of E and F, the answer is 6,

mydesired result is like follows

```
parent numberOfSet
A      2
D      6
```

Are there any good ways to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CTE` to fetch required stocks per parent and child combination then get `minimum` set using the following query:

```
with cte as
 (select parent, child, count(1) as cnt from composition group by parent, child)
select c.parent, trunc(coalesce(min(s.stock/c.cnt),0)) as min_set
  from cte c
  left join stocks s on c.child = s.code
group by c.parent
```